# What did Murdock put in his coffin water bed?

Tags: marvel, daredevil, daredevil-2003

I just recently watched the Director's Cut of Daredevil. In it, it shows that Murdock puts a white crystaline substance in his water before climbing into his bed. What was this?

[image]

Comment: My guess would be salt; it's easier to float in salt water

Comment: I thought that, too. But it seems to be, to me, too white to be salt.

Comment: A cursory skim of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_tank) suggests that it could be [epsom salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_sulfate), which is a very white powder

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not aware of official word regarding the *Daredevil* movie<sup>1</sup>, but Murdock's "bed" closely resembles an [isolation tank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_tank). To compare, here's Daredevil's tank:

[image: Batfleck, pre-Batman]
[image: Batfleck, part 2]

And here's a guy laying in an *actual* isolation tank used in relaxation therapy:

[image: A real actor. Also, an isolation tank]

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_tank#Tank_design_and_usage), modern isolation tanks use a solution of epsom salt to increase water density. [Epsom salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_sulfate) is a *very* white substance:

[image: Crystalline epsom salt]

So I'm going to say the powder is probably that: epsom salt.

---

<sup>1</sup> Truthfully, I think everybody involved just wants to purge it from their memory.  But that's just me being cynical

Comment: You show epsom as a powder, but as I mentioned in my question, and show in my picture, it's a very crystaline substance. That's not to say you're wrong. Just the image you posted looks nothing like what was used.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Looks like just a different level of granularity; I added a picture that's a bit more coarse-grain. Daredevil's looks like it's coarser still (it actually looks more like road salt to me, or water softener salt), but it's definitely *some* kind of salt

Comment: @MyCodeSucks looking at the article for epsom, it seems to come in a crystalline variety which looks more like the screenshot from the film - more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsomite

Comment: As a kid, my family used to go through so much Epsom salts because my sister and I learned that we could add coloring (and essential oils) to make bath salts (this predates that being a common name for a drug) and insisting on making bath salts for all of the family, as gifts, etc. Even got our Junior Achievement group to make that a product one year...

Answer (score 3):

The film's [screenplay](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/daredevil-2003.pdf) indicates that this is a floatation tank, and what he's putting in it are [**Epsom Salts**](https://floatworks.com/journal/why-floatation-tanks-use-epsom-salts#:%7E:text=Epsom%20Salt%20Floatation%20tanks%20are%20an%20excellent%20way%20of%20combating%20stress%2C%20alleviating%20muscular%20aches%20and%20pains%20and%20for%20reaching%20Zen%20like%20states%20of%20relaxation.%20Soaking%20in%20Epsom%20salts%20has%20been%20found%20to%20stimulate%20lymph%20drainage%2C%20and%20promote%20the%20absorption%20of%20Magnesium%20and%20Sulphates.).

> **WOMAN'S VOICE (CONT'D):** *Then I realized...this ia the next level.*
>
> Matt slides open a third drawer to reveal a white bag full of Epsom Salts. He scoops up a handful and steps into...
>
> THE LIVING ROOM.
> He stops before what appears to be a coffin. But then he
> opens the lid to reveal it's a FLOATATION TANK. He drops the
> Epsom Salts into the tank and strips off his costume.
>
> **WOMAN'S VOICE (CONT'D):** *Good-bye, Matt. I hope you find whatever
> it is you're looking for.*
>
> CLICK.
>
> Matt slides into the warm water and closes his eyes.